# How to show APNS Device token with UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiresponder

I want show a APNS device token with UILabel.

So I coded below:

```
//AppDelegate.m

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
// TODO: Pass the token to our server
NSString *devToken = [[[[deviceToken description] 
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] 
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


NSString *str = [NSString 
                 stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",devToken];
UIAlertView *alertCtr = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Token is " message:devToken delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alertCtr show];
NSLog(@"device token - %@",str);
viewc = [ViewController alloc];

viewc.tokenLabel.text = str;

}
```

But nothing happend. What's wrong?

Comment: Does your NSLog output the proper information? Is token label a propertly synthesized property?

Comment: And you're sure the application actually successfully registers and gets a device token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewc = [ViewController alloc];
viewc.tokenLabel.text = str;
```

After `alloc`'ing your view controller, you should `init` it too. And present it, whether modally or in a navigation controller or something else, it's up to you.

Comment: I got the error.. 'Use of undeclared identifier 'init'; did you mean 'int'?'

Comment: Like in `viewc = [[ViewController alloc] init]`.